# Cookie is not working and returning undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I'm using the following code for my set and get Cookie:

```
$.setCookie = function (c_name, value, exdays) {
    var exdate = new Date();
    exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
    var c_value = escape(value) + ((exdays == null) ? "" : "; expires=" + exdate.toUTCString());
    document.cookie = c_name + "=" + c_value;
};
$.getCookie = function (c_name) {
    var i, x, y, ARRcookies = document.cookie.split(";");
    for (i = 0; i < ARRcookies.length; i++) {
        x = ARRcookies[i].substr(0, ARRcookies[i].indexOf("="));
        y = ARRcookies[i].substr(ARRcookies[i].indexOf("=") + 1);
        x = x.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "");
        if (x == c_name) {
            return unescape(y);
        }
    }
};
```

Then I simply created two test `click` functions for `2` buttons:

```
$('#quick-true').click(function(){
$.setCookie('quick-status', true, 365);
var get = $.getCookie('quick-status');
alert('Status: '+get);
});
$('#quick-false').click(function(){
$.setCookie('quick-status', false, 365);
var get = $.getCookie('quick-status');
alert('Status: '+get)
});
```

But when clicking either `#quick-true` or `#quick-false` the alert says `Status: undefined`
Can anyone help me why this is happening. I know quite a bit about Cookies and I worked with them a lot but this time im lost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks fine to me, but to be sure I created a test [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/ta4Tx/1/), and it's working as expected for me.
There's probably something other than the code you have posted that is causing the problem, exactly what is hard to tell.

Comment: Thanks. Well, I was trying to make the cookie to work without actually having the site hosted. So I was trying to get then cookie to work on: 'file:///C:/Users/Shawn/Desktop/project.html?page=index'. But it doesn't work like that. So once I hosted it to `x10` it worked. Thanks for the answer.